# Podio Calculation field issue

Tags: podio

We have an issue with a calculation field not always working. (We have about 5 calculation fields that are similar so same applies to all).
See in the attached example. 
The Textbook item has a calc field 'Set Text'. One of the values in there is showing 'Null'.
Most of the time this works fine but in about 8% of the cases it has this null error.

See the other screenshot of the Aggregator item. The field that is being referenced there is correct.

To fix it we have to manually remove the relationship between the two items and then put it back again, to force the calculation to recalculate. This fixes the issue. So the problem does not seem to be the formula but rather the calculation being performed incorrectly.

The Aggregator items are created and joined to the Textbook item through the API.

This is a big issue for us as we use this value to post to our website so the manual fix is not a practical solution.

Podio support please advice what the issue is here 
[Aggregator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvYff.png)

[Null error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXis8.png)

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing too many details about your specific workflow and structure, let me offer some ideas:

Podio calculation fields can begin to act in strange ways if the original field is being referenced by calculation fields too many levels deep. What I mean by this is that if the original field that shows the Paper Code (or whatever that int showing null is) is being referenced through too many calculation fields, it can begin to cause problems in cases of updating and adding new items. This is most definitely a bug I've encountered with large-scale systems, but there are workarounds.

First off, I see that you have all of the pertinent non-concatenated fields at the bottom of your Aggregator app. Try manually concatenating those fields in the Textbooks app (where you're doing the result.push) instead of referencing the Web course text calc field exclusively.

If that doesn't work and you're proficient with the API, a longer workaround could be that after the automation runs, you wait a sufficient time (say 30 seconds) until the calculation field updates, have the API check for the text "null" in the calculation field, and refreshes the relationship fields if null is found.

Comment: Thanks for your response @NathanaelBennett. I will ask our dev to look at this. Much appreciated